# Математика, статистика, теория вероятностей - что нужно знать будущему Data Since самоучке?

Tags: математика, статистика, теория-вероятностей, дискретная-математика

Последний раз учил математику на первом курсе, на классе статистики. Прошло четыре года, ничего не помню.

Что необходимо знать для того что-бы успешно и фундаментально развиваться в Computer science and Data science? Какие предметы должны быть must have у самоучки?

Если можно, дайте ответ в формате: предмет/направление математики - её роль в моем IT-будущем.

Comment: Боюсь, ваш вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. Тут допустимы только чёткие ответы, про которые можно ознозначно сказать верны они или нет. Ваш вопрос таких ответов не подразумевает. Да и что мы можем вам посоветовать?? Мы же про вас ничегошеньки не знаем.

Comment: @mymedia да, пусть расскажет о себе

Comment: Читать книги по популярной математике - Штейнгауз, Перельман, Гарднер. Зарегистрируйтесь на сайте https://brilliant.org - там задачи по всем направлениям.

Comment: Прошу прощения за некорректноть вопроса. 
Мне 22, отучился на финансиста, работаю фин аналитиком.
Хочу учить python и работать с mssqlsms. Математику хочу выучить для поступления на курс data scince на coursera. У меня нет базы, нет фундаментальных знаний.

Answer (score 1):

«Математику уже затем учить надо, что она ум в порядок приводит» - М.В. Ломоносов. Как и в любом деле, все зависит от решаемой задачи. Но в целом вот базовый список знаний, который я думаю должен освоить в той или иной степени каждый уважающий себя программист.

Школьная математика

1. Арифметика: найти сумму арифмет. прогрессии
2. Тригонометрия: пересчет угла между двумя точками (пример: глаза смотрят на курсор)
3. Вычислительная геометрия: Определение пересечения отрезков \ областей (посчитать когда курсор который тащит что-то заходит в опр. область)
4. Начала мат. анализа: вопросы Θ-оценки алгоритмов

Университетский уровень

1. Дискретная математика: корректно отрицать выражения, битовые операции, теория графов (логика под if, бит-маски)
2. Линейная алгебра: матричные операции, системы линейных уравнений (повороты изображений)

Плюсы в знании математики весомые, однако в университете кроме дискретной математики и линейной алгебры дают еще тонны (МатАн, ФункАн, ДифУравнения, ТФКП, Теория управления, ...) различных курсов, которые весьма косвенно относятся к программированию. Я больше скажу, память человека так устроена, что всё что не нужно — забывается. Учить тому что «может быть понадобится» — означает бесполезную безвозвратную трату времени. Даже тем, кому понадобится — придётся учить заново.